# Intersection between spatial lines and spatial polygon to identify

Tags: spatial, intersection

I am trying to identify the spatial lines that intersect with the polygon to eliminate them

I have tried various packages to do this work but all of them are giving the same error "Error in RGEOSBinPredFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, func) : 
  IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements"

Spatial lines and polygon can be downloaded from this link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CWzZzZucBjhfAthApnOGgSEL7dLXlPt5

library (rgeos)

lines_onland<-gIntersection(my.lines, polygons,byid=TRUE)
"Error in RGEOSBinPredFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, func) : 
  IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements"

lines_onland<-gIntersect(my.lines, polygons,byid=TRUE)
"Error in RGEOSBinPredFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, func) : 
  IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements"

library(raster)

lines_onland<- raster::intersect(my.lines, polygons)
Error in RGEOSBinPredFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, func) : 
  IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements

Lines crossing land

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
library(raster)
my.lines <- shapefile("my.lines.shp")
polygons <- shapefile("polygons.shp")
```

First find out where the error occurs

```
err <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(my.lines)) {
    x <- try(raster::intersect(my.lines[i,], polygons))
    if (class(x) == "try-error") {
        err <- c(err, i)
    }
}

err
#[1]  48  59 191 294
```

The error occurs for four lines that consist of a single location, which makes them invalid

```
geom(my.lines[err,])
#     object part cump         x        y
#[1,]      1    1    1 -28.53502 38.53658
#[2,]      2    1    2 -28.53413 38.53638
#[3,]      3    1    3 -28.54550 38.53687
#[4,]      4    1    4 -28.53340 38.53602
```

Remove the invalid lines and things work as they should

```
x <- raster::intersect(my.lines[-err,], polygons)
```